# Preventing Flickering on Postbacks without Ajax

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc-4, postback

I am creating an MVC 4 Website and I am experiencing some UX challenges. On Postbacks my website content flickers as the page changes. I have done some research on this and found most people solve this issue using Ajax. My company does not like the idea of using Ajax on this project, so I am hunting for a solution that does not involve Ajax. I read some people recommending using JavaScript for this, but couldn't find any examples or guidance.

My boss suggested I play around with css transitions and hard-coding dimensions to help reduce flickering effect. I haven't had any luck with either of those suggestions.

Is fixing this issue even possible without using Ajax?

Comment: What changes cause the postbacks? Data retrieval or simple visual changes?

Comment: If you are bringing up a new page with new data, you will need to use an ajax call.  If it is just showing different data from the model being passed you can do that with jquery/css.  Angular/Knockout are some pretty cool tools for showing different content also

Comment: @MattBodily That would be challenging, since TO said, he isn't allowed to use AJAX. Have fun with angular, then :D

Comment: Completely agree.  really cut off at the knees without ajax.

Comment: Thanks everyone for your input. I should mention that the flickering does not occur every postback. It seems to be completely random since switching to a specific View will cause the flickering, but switching to that same view at other times is smooth with no flickering at all.

Comment: @tymeJV the postbacks are caused by simply changing Views. I'm changing out HTML, but I'm just developing the UI, so there is no real data retrieval.

Comment: As others pointed out using AJAX or any other js framework (Angular/Knockout) will give you what you want. You see the flickering because you might be changing the control dimensions for controls like `@Html.TextBox` or `@Html.ListBoxFor` etc through css which might differ from their default styles (height and width) which might cause flickering. This might be sporadic even for the same page and it all determined by how speedy your page renders controlled by lot of other factors.

Comment: @DennisR I really appreciate your detailed explanation!! I will look into Angular/Knockout for solutions.